# Performance Test -Jmeter- Testing an Async process

Tags: jmeter

I have a load test plan which posts requests to an API. After the API successfully processing these requests. There are Async processes that process these requests and store the processed request in a NoSQL database.
my goal of the load test is to see whether all my requests are successfully persisted in the database.
in order to test this- I have to save my hashkey and sortKey from my requests - how can this be achieved? and also once the load test is done I have to do these validations
so I have to write a separate validation script after sending the request  . is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in a single shot like:

1. Send an API request using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Extract the `hashKey` and the `sortKey` using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (most probably [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide))
3. "Wait" for the "async" process to finish by querying the NoSQL database under the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)
4. You can also put the whole sequence under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) so JMeter would measure the "end-to-end" time for the whole scenario

Comment: is it in a while controller i will be calling my java method to do the querying of the database?

Comment: is it in a while controller i will be calling my java method to do the querying of the database?